# How to get the original html string in innerHTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, innerhtml, highlight.js

Problem : When i tried to use the highlight.js about jsx code, disappear html tag.

original source:

```
<pre>
    <code class="javascript">
    const { Link } = ReactRouter;

    App.QnAChild = React.createClass({
      mixins: [Mixins.Accounts, Mixins.Utils],

      render() {
        let name = "";

        if (this.props.user && this.props.user.name) {
          name = this.props.user.name;
        }    

        return (
          <tr>
            <td>
              {this.props.index + 1}
            </td>
            <td>
              <Link to={`/qna/${ this.props._id }`}
                    className="title-link"> {this.props.title}
              </Link>
            </td>
            <td>
              <Link to="">
                {name}
              </Link>
            </td>
            <td>
              {this.momentKoreanDate(this.props.createdAt, 5)}
            </td>
          </tr>
        )
      }
    });        
    </code>
</pre>
```

after render source :

```
const { Link } = ReactRouter;
App.QnAChild = React.createClass({
    mixins: [Mixins.Accounts, Mixins.Utils],
    render() {
        let name = "";
        if (this.props.user && this.props.user.name) {
            name = this.props.user.name;
        }
        return (
            {this.props.index + 1}
            {this.props.title}
            {name}
            {this.momentKoreanDate(this.props.createdAt, 5)}
        )
    }
});
```

$('pre code')[0].innerHTML:

```
"const { Link } = ReactRouter; App.QnAChild = React.createClass({ mixins: [Mixins.Accounts, Mixins.Utils], render() { let name = ""; if (this.props.user &amp;&amp; this.props.user.name) { name = this.props.user.name; } return ( {this.props.index + 1} <link to="{`/qna/${" this.props._id="" }`}="" classname="title-link"> {this.props.title} <link to=""> {name} {this.momentKoreanDate(this.props.createdAt, 5)} ) } });  "
```

Why disappear html tag in innerHTML?
How to get the original html string in innerHTML?

I hope to source after render :

```
const { Link } = ReactRouter;

App.QnAChild = React.createClass({
    mixins: [Mixins.Accounts, Mixins.Utils],

        render() {
            let name = "";

            if (this.props.user && this.props.user.name) {
                name = this.props.user.name;
            }    

            return (
            <tr>
                <td>
                    {this.props.index + 1}
                </td>
                <td>
                    <Link to={`/qna/${ this.props._id }`}
                          className="title-link"> {this.props.title}
                    </Link>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <Link to="">
                    {name}
                    </Link>
                </td>
                <td>
                    {this.momentKoreanDate(this.props.createdAt, 5)}
                </td>
            </tr>
        )
    }
});
```

Thank you for your patient :)

Have a nice day!

Comment: The < and the > should be entities

Answer (score 1):

`"<" = &lt; (lower then)`

`">" = &gt; (greater then)`

```html
<pre>
    <code class="javascript">
    const { Link } = ReactRouter;

    App.QnAChild = React.createClass({
      mixins: [Mixins.Accounts, Mixins.Utils],

      render() {
        let name = "";

        if (this.props.user && this.props.user.name) {
          name = this.props.user.name;
        }    

        return (
          &lt;tr&gt;
            &lt;td&gt;
              {this.props.index + 1}
            &lt;/td&gt;
            &lt;td&gt;
              &lt;Link to={`/qna/${ this.props._id }`}
                    className="title-link"> {this.props.title}
              &lt;/Link&gt;
            &lt;/td&gt;
            &lt;td&gt;
              &lt;Link to=""&gt;
                {name}
              &lt;/Link&gt;
            &lt;/td&gt;
            &lt;td&gt;
              {this.momentKoreanDate(this.props.createdAt, 5)}
            &lt;/td&gt;
          &lt;/tr&gt;
        )
      }
    });        
    </code>
</pre>
```

You should store the code in a variable:

```
var myCode = "<html>";
var processed = yourProcessor(myCode);
$('pre code').innerHTML = processed;
```

Comment: Thank you !!

I tried to replace source..

innerHTML.replace(/</gi,"&lt;");
innerHTML.replace(/>/gi,"&gt;");

so, I want to get original code in innerHTML... : )

Comment: i found to disappear to table tag(tr, td) in innerHTML...
other tag(div, span) is exist in innerHTML...
i don't understand that..

Comment: @ProgrammingPearls sorry don't understand what you mean, can you update your question, or provide an example?